# Unexpected behaviour of MEL function after upgrade to Mule Runtime 3.8.1

Tags: mule, dataweave, mule-el, mvel

I have the following MEL function:

```
def createSomething(foo){
    if (org.springframework.util.StringUtils.isEmpty(foo)){
        return org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.remove(java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString(), '-');
    }
    if (foo.toString().length() <= 32){
        return foo;
    }
    String fooWithoutHyphens = org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.remove(foo.toString(), '-');
    if (fooWithoutHyphens.length() <= 32){
        return fooWithoutHyphens;
    }
    return foo.toString().substring(0, 32);
}
```

that is being called from a DWL file:

```
%var mySomething = createSomething("foo")
```

This is working fine on Mule Runtime 3.7.2.

However after an upgrade to Mule Runtime 3.8.1 I receive the following exception:

```
com.mulesoft.weave.mule.exception.WeaveExecutionException: Exception while executing: 
Unknown
Not enough arguments (1) for function with parameters (foo, 

fooWithoutHyphens)..
    at com.mulesoft.weave.mule.exception.WeaveExecutionException$.apply(WeaveExecutionException.scala:12)
    at com.mulesoft.weave.mule.WeaveMessageProcessor.execute(WeaveMessageProcessor.scala:121)
    at com.mulesoft.weave.mule.WeaveMessageProcessor.process(WeaveMessageProcessor.scala:67)
    at com.mulesoft.weave.mule.WeaveMessageProcessor$$FastClassByCGLIB$$216b1542.invoke(<generated>)
```

When I provide anything as a second argument to the function, e.g.

```
%var mySomething = createSomething("foo", 0)
```

the exception doesn't occur, although as far as I can tell the function doesn't work as expected.

What is the reason of this behaviour and how can it be fixed?

UPDATE: If the following part:

```
String fooWithoutHyphens = org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.remove(foo.toString(), '-');
if (fooWithoutHyphens.length() <= 32){
    return fooWithoutHyphens;
}
```

is removed or replaced with:

```
  if (org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.remove(foo.toString(), '-').length() <= 32){
        return org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.remove(foo.toString(), '-');
    }
```

the exception is not thrown. It seems that the declarated string fooWithoutHyphens is now treated as an argument, but I don't know why.

Comment: Strange, according to your exception it is a though you defined your function as `createSomething(foo, fooWithoutHyphens)`. Are you sure another definition does not exists somewhere else?

Comment: @Pierre B. Initially I though the same thing, but I wasn't able to find any other occurrence. I will check again though.

Comment: @Pierre B. It's this function. See the update part of my question.

Comment: The official doc is succinct on the use of global MEL function, and nowhere it mentions such variable declaration: `String fooWithoutHyphens = ...`, even if it worked on Mule 3.7 there's no guarantee it will continue to work on later versions. I think the work around you used if your example may be a good way to go, or if you require more complex transformation using global MEL function may not be the best way to go.

Comment: @Pierre B. Thanks, this explanation is enough for me. If you write an answer based on it I'll accept it.

Comment: Happy to help! I added this as an answer with a few more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official doc is succinct on the use of global MEL function, and nowhere is mentioned variable declaration such as `String fooWithoutHyphens = ...`. Related documentation can be found on the [MEL Docs](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/mule-expression-language-tips#global-configuration) and [DataWeave docs](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/dataweave-language-introduction#calling-global-mel-functions-from-dataweave-code) for 3.8.

Even if your example worked on Mule 3.7 there's no guarantee it will continue to work on later versions considering it is not documented. I think the work around you used in your example may be a good way to go, or if you require more complex transformation using global MEL function may not be the best way to go.